# Creating a Socket Connection in Store App not Working

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-8

I have just released an app to the Windows Phone Store, after thoroughly debugging, and the functionality when testing in debug and release mode is not the same as when I use the app that was downloaded from the store. When testing in debug and release mode from my solution I have no issues (on device or on emulator) and everything works great. After downloading from the store I only return the `SocketError.NetworkDown` error?

I am creating a Socket connection to gather network interface information.

```
private async void UpdateCurrentInterface()
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // To run this application you should specify the name of a server on your network that is running
        // the required service. 
        string serverName = "www.bing.com";

        // This identifies the port over which to communicate.
        int portNumber = 80;

        // Create DnsEndPoint. 
        DnsEndPoint hostEntry = new DnsEndPoint(serverName, portNumber);

        // Create a SocketAsyncEventArgs object to be used in the connection request.
        SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = hostEntry;
        socketEventArg.UserToken = socket;
        socketEventArg.Completed += ShowNetworkInterfaceInformation1;

        // // Make an asynchronous Connect request over the socket.
        socket.ConnectAsync(socketEventArg);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Display the network information using the GetCurrentNetworkInterface extension method on the socket.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>This is the callback from the ConnectAsync method.</remarks>
    private void ShowNetworkInterfaceInformation1(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        // When ConnectAsync was called it was passed the socket object in
        // the UserToken field of the socketEventArg. This context is retrieved once
        // the ConnectAsync has completed.
        Socket socket = e.UserToken as Socket;

        // Only call GetCurrentNetworkInterface if the connection was successful.
        if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
        {
            NetworkInterfaceInfo netInterfaceInfo = socket.GetCurrentNetworkInterface();

            // We are making UI updates, so make sure these happen on the UI thread.
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                currentTypeTextBlock.Text = GetInterfaceTypeString(netInterfaceInfo.InterfaceType);

                currentNameTextBlock.Text = name = netInterfaceInfo.InterfaceName;

                string change = "";
                if (netInterfaceInfo.InterfaceState.ToString() == "Connected")
                    currentStateTextBlock.Text = "connected";
                else
                    currentStateTextBlock.Text = "disconnected";

            });

        }
        else if (e.SocketError == SocketError.NetworkDown)
        {
            DisplayMessage("Could not connect.", "Network Down Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }

        // Close our socket since we no longer need it.
        socket.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What did you include in your manifest?

Comment: Regarding App Capabilities? ID_CAP_LOCATION and ID_CAP_MAP for other features.

Comment: Seeing as this is a Silverlight app, i'm pretty sure you HAVE to have ID_CAP_NETWORKING.

Comment: I will make the update and get back. Any reason why you could tell me it worked when testing but not on the store?

Comment: @zaitsman You were right about including `ID_CAP_NETWORKING`. Not sure why it worked before it was launched ot the store but I hope this helps others as well! Much appreciated this saved me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `ID_CAP_NETWORKING` as a capability within `WMAppManifest`.